# 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found when importing from google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client after tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-bigquery

I noticed a very strange behaviour when importing the bigquery Client:

The following works:

```py
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
import tensorflow as tf
```

The following **does not** work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
```

as the second import fails with

```
....
File /opt/conda/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py:373, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    370 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
    372 if handle is None:
--> 373     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374 else:
    375     self._handle = handle

OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /opt/conda/miniconda3/lib/./libgeos.so.3.10.2)
```

The second workaround I have found is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/conda/miniconda3/lib`. So I am either very careful about the import order, or I specify on my OS the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

That being said, I'd like to understand what exactly makes this break when I'm importing **tensorflow** **first** or rather what makes this work when I import the `Client` first. From a little debug I know that both examples try to load the same lib `/opt/conda/miniconda3/lib/libgeos_c.so`.

Versions:

```
tf 2.11.0
bigquery client version: 3.12.0 
python '3.8.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 22 2022, 08:46:39) \n[GCC 10.4.0]'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you first import **TensorFlow** and then the **Google Cloud BigQuery client** (`import tensorflow as tf` followed by `from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client`). When you import TensorFlow, it may also load its own set of shared libraries. If there's a shared library conflict with the BigQuery client, it can lead to an error.

The error you're encountering `OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found` is likely related to a version conflict with the C++ Standard Library `libstdc++`. TensorFlow may be loading a version of libstdc++ that's not compatible with the version required by the **libgeos_c.so.3.10.2** library.

The first sequence works because it loads libraries in a compatible order, whereas the second sequence may lead to conflicts if shared libraries have incompatible dependencies.

Setting **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** to **/opt/conda/miniconda3/lib** essentially tells the system to prioritize libraries in that path. By setting this environment variable, you are influencing the dynamic library loader to look in that path first, and it can find the compatible version of **libgeos_c.so.3.10.2**, which resolves the error.